# ToolBar overflow behavior sometimes not working after reordering

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I drag toolbars and change size of the window toolbar's overflow behavior doesn't work. It is simply cut. I need overflow behavior after dragging.
Screenshots:

## 1

Initial state. Last toolbar doesn't have enough space - overflow strategy is applied.
http://prntscr.com/4pi3yh

## 2

After toolbar reordering and changing window's size(random). For some reason some toolbars are simply cut when there is no enough space for them. No overflow strategy is applied.
http://prntscr.com/4pi40t

Here is xaml and there is no code-behind:

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow"
            Width="525"
            Height="350">
        <ToolBarTray>
            <ToolBar>
                <Button>Text 1</Button>
                <Button>Text 1</Button>
                <Button>Text 1</Button>
                <Button>Text 1</Button>
                <Button>Text 1</Button>
            </ToolBar>
            <ToolBar>
                <Button>Text 2</Button>
                <Button>Text 2</Button>
                <Button>Text 2</Button>
                <Button>Text 2</Button>
                <Button>Text 2</Button>
            </ToolBar>
            <ToolBar>
                <Button>Text 3</Button>
                <Button>Text 3</Button>
                <Button>Text 3</Button>
                <Button>Text 3</Button>
                <Button>Text 3</Button>
                <Button>Text 3</Button>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
    </Window>
```

I've noticed that toolbar's Width property is changed from Auto(NaN) to some particular width after dragging. And Toolbar which has Width != Auto are cut. I think ToolBarTray changes Width property while dragging or something.
Any solution or workaround will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround for this issue. If you know some better solution - please tell me. 
As I wrote Width is change by ToolBarTray so we need to change it back to Auto. This code does the trick:

```
        var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ToolBar.WidthProperty, typeof(ToolBar));
        dpd.AddValueChanged(AssociatedObject,
            delegate
            {
                if(!double.IsNaN(AssociatedObject.Width))
                    AssociatedObject.Width = double.NaN;
            });
```